# Problema con SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

estoy intentando pintar unos resultados por pantalla en SQL Developer y no soy capaz, si os dais cuenta tengo habilitada la salida DBMS para esa conexión, pero las sentencias DBMS aparecen en un color muy claro, como si estuviesen deshabilitadas. Pero luego el script se ejecuta sin problemas.

[image: SQL Developer]

Comment: ¿Será que la salida esta ahí pero con letras negras? Intenta seleccionar/copiar el contenido de la salida.

Answer (score 1):

Nueva característica en SQL Developer.

El código PL / SQL de tipo LOGGING o debug tiene un nuevo esquema de coloración de sintaxis PL / SQL.

Si no le gusta esto, puede deshabilitarlo o cambiar el color a otra cosa.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La idea: el código de INSTRUMENTACIÓN puede ser una distracción cuando buscas revisar el código de tu aplicación. Entonces, ¿por qué no una opción para tener un color diferente para que sus ojos puedan ingresar los bits importantes de su código?

Comment: lo siento - Olvidé que tenía habilitado el traductor de google

Answer (score 0):

El problema esta en que SQL Developer 19 y Oracle XE 10g, no son compatibles, se debería o bien upgradear SQL Developer o instalar Oracle XE 11g en adelante.

Comment: Si tiene 10g, sí, no podremos sondear la salida de dbms; el cambio en los controladores jdbc causó esto. Agregué una respuesta para explicar por qué su código es 'gris